# How to convert a string to a list, split by the string '\n\n\n\n\n'?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string with text and \n's in it. Like:

```
"Information moreinformation moreinformation \n\n\n\n\n Information moreinformation moreinformation \n\n\n\n\n Information moreinformation moreinformation"
```

Now I want a list, split by the \n\n\n\n\n strings. So I want:

```
['Information moreinformation moreinformation', 'Information moreinformation moreinformation', 'Information moreinformation moreinformation']
```

I already tried this, but this doesn't work. Then I still have a string.

```
with open ("file.txt", "r") as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    content = ' '.join(content)
    content.split('\n\n\n\n\n')

print (content)
```

Comment: Strings are **immutable**. All operations on strings *return* the result instead of modifying the argument. Hence:  `content = content.split('...')` does the trick.

Comment: Thanks! It worked :)

Comment: Mind posting a sample of your text file?...May be this can be solved in a better way

Answer (score 0):

```
   content =  content.split('\n\n\n\n\n')
```

Try this. You did not change content variable's datatype otherwise.